# Multiline Regex with opening and closing word

Tags: regex, multiline

I need to admit, I'm very basic if it comes to RegEx expressions.
I have an app written in C# that looks for certain Regex expressions in text files. I'm not sure how to explain my problem so I will go straight to example.

My text:

```
   DeviceNr : 30
     DeviceClass = ABC
     UnitNr = 1
     Reference = 29
     PhysState = ENABLED
    LogState = OPERATIVE
     DevicePlan = 702
     Manufacturer = CDE
     Model = EFG
    ready
    
    DeviceNr : 31
     DeviceClass = ABC
     UnitNr = 9
     Reference = 33
     PhysState = ENABLED
    LogState = OPERATIVE
     Manufacturer = DDD
     Model = XYZ
    Description = something here
    ready
```

I need to match a multiline text that starts with "DeviceNr" word, ends with "ready" and have "DeviceClass = ABC" and "Model = XYZ" - I can only assume that this lines will be in this exact order, but I cannot assume what will be between them, not even number of other lines between them. I tried with below regex, but it matched the whole text instead of only DeviceNr : 31

```
DeviceNr : ([0-9]+)(?:.*?\n)*? DeviceClass = ABC(?:.*?\n)*? Model = XYZ(?:.*?\n)*?ready\n\n
```

Comment: Is this what you looking for? `(?=(DeviceNr.*?ready))` Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nZj7wS/2

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but what about the part where I need to match "DeviceClass = ABC" and "Model = XYZ" lines between "DeviceNr" and "ready" ?

Comment: Check this: `(?=DeviceNr.*?(DeviceClass\s=\s\w+).*?(Model\s=\s\w+).*ready)` Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nZj7wS/3/

Comment: It's still not giving me what I need. https://regex101.com/r/MBXSht/1 I need it to be only one match (the second one), I need to know that I matched both lines, and that they are placed within "DeviceNr" and the FIRST found "ready" word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that `"DeviceClass = ABC" and "Model = XYZ"` are present and in that order, you can also make use of a lookahead assertion on a per line bases first matching all lines that do not contain for example `DeviceNr`

Then match the lines that does, and also do this for `Model` and `ready`

```php
^\s*DeviceNr : ([0-9]+)(?:\r?\n(?!\s*DeviceClass =).*)*\r?\n\s*DeviceClass = ABC\b(?:\r?\n(?!\s*Model =).*)*\r?\n\s*Model = XYZ\b(?:\r?\n(?!\s*ready).*)*\r?\n\s*ready\b
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\s*DeviceNr : ([0-9]+)` Match `DeviceNr :`  and capture 1+ digits 0-9 in **group 1**
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n(?!\s*DeviceClass =).*` Match a newline, and assert that the line does not contain `DeviceClass =`
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat as you don't know how much lines there are
- `\r?\n\s*DeviceClass = ABC\b` Match a newline, optional whitespace chars and  `DeviceClass = ABC`
- `(?:\r?\n(?!\s*Model =).*)*\r?\n\s*Model = XYZ\b` The previous approach also for `Model =`
- `(?:\r?\n(?!\s*ready).*)*\r?\n\s*ready\b` And the same approach for `ready`

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cs*DeviceNr+%3a+%28%5b0-9%5d%2b%29%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!%5cs*DeviceClass+%3d%29.*%29*%5cr%3f%5cn%5cs*DeviceClass+%3d+ABC%5cb%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!%5cs*Model+%3d%29.*%29*%5cr%3f%5cn%5cs*Model+%3d+XYZ%5cb%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!%5cs*ready%29.*%29*%5cr%3f%5cn%5cs*ready%5cb&i=+++DeviceNr+%3a+30%0d%0a+++++DeviceClass+%3d+ABC%0d%0a+++++UnitNr+%3d+1%0d%0a+++++Reference+%3d+29%0d%0a+++++PhysState+%3d+ENABLED%0d%0a++++LogState+%3d+OPERATIVE%0d%0a+++++DevicePlan+%3d+702%0d%0a+++++Manufacturer+%3d+CDE%0d%0a+++++Model+%3d+EFG%0d%0a++++ready%0d%0a++++%0d%0a++++DeviceNr+%3a+31%0d%0a+++++DeviceClass+%3d+ABC%0d%0a+++++UnitNr+%3d+9%0d%0a+++++Reference+%3d+33%0d%0a+++++PhysState+%3d+ENABLED%0d%0a++++LogState+%3d+OPERATIVE%0d%0a+++++Manufacturer+%3d+DDD%0d%0a+++++Model+%3d+XYZ%0d%0a++++Description+%3d+something+here%0d%0a++++ready&o=m)

Note that `\s` can also match a newline. If you want to prevent that, you can also use `[^\S\r\n]` to match a whitespace char without a newline.

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d*DeviceNr+%3a+%28%5b0-9%5d%2b%29%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d*DeviceClass+%3d%29.*%29*%5cr%3f%5cn%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d*DeviceClass+%3d+ABC%5cb%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d*Model+%3d%29.*%29*%5cr%3f%5cn%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d*Model+%3d+XYZ%5cb%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d*ready%29.*%29*%5cr%3f%5cn%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d*ready%5cb&i=+++DeviceNr+%3a+30%0d%0a+++++DeviceClass+%3d+ABC%0d%0a+++++UnitNr+%3d+1%0d%0a+++++Reference+%3d+29%0d%0a+++++PhysState+%3d+ENABLED%0d%0a++++LogState+%3d+OPERATIVE%0d%0a+++++DevicePlan+%3d+702%0d%0a+++++Manufacturer+%3d+CDE%0d%0a+++++Model+%3d+EFG%0d%0a++++ready%0d%0a++++%0d%0a++++DeviceNr+%3a+31%0d%0a+++++DeviceClass+%3d+ABC%0d%0a+++++UnitNr+%3d+9%0d%0a+++++Reference+%3d+33%0d%0a+++++PhysState+%3d+ENABLED%0d%0a++++LogState+%3d+OPERATIVE%0d%0a+++++Manufacturer+%3d+DDD%0d%0a+++++Model+%3d+XYZ%0d%0a++++Description+%3d+something+here%0d%0a++++ready&o=m)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! and thanks for the explanation, it's very complex pattern but it does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you want to match 'DeviceNr : 31' followed by 'DeviceClass = ABC' (possibly with some intervening characters) followed by 'Model = XYZ' (again possibly with some intervening characters) followed by 'ready' (again possibly with some intervening characters) **making sure that none of those intervening characters are actually the start of of another 'DeviceNr' section**.

So to match arbitrary intervening characters with the above enforcement, we can use the following regex expression that uses a *negative lookahead assertion*:

```
(?:(?!DeviceNr)[\s\S])*?
```

1. `(?:` - Start of a non-capturing group
2. `(?!DeviceNr)` - Asserts that the next characters of the input are not  'DeviceNr'
3. `[\s\S]` - Matches a whitespace or non-whitespace character, i.e. *any* character
4. `)` end of the non-capturing group
5. `*?` non-greedily match 0 or more characters as long as the next input does not match 'DeviceNr'

Then it's a simple matter to use the above regex repeatedly as follows:

```
DeviceNr : (\d+)\n(?:(?!DeviceNr)[\s\S])*?DeviceClass = ABC\n(?:(?!DeviceNr)[\s\S])*?Model = XYZ\n(?:(?!DeviceNr)[\s\S])*?ready
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/x8pQdl/1/)

Capture Group 1 will have the `DeviceNr` value.

**Important Note**

The above regex is quite expensive in terms of the number of steps required for execution since it must check the negative lookahead assertion at just about every character position once it has matched `DeviceNr : (\d+)`.